# convert urls.py url to path

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Im trying to follow a tutorial on web application hacking. the instructor has us building a web app using django. I realized that his version of python, django and probably everything else is older than mine and Im running into conversion issues as Im not quite a web developer. :) please look at the two images and help me convert his setup from urls.py url to the django 2.0 version of path. Thank you!

this is his screen....and then  mine.
[image: His version]
[My version](https://screenrec.com/share/uiG1PwWN7v)

Comment: FYI: Never paste your code as images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('request/', tauntaun_request),
    path('', tauntaun_request),
]
```

Comment: Thank you! One last question when I copied the "from" it gave me the following error ---from tautaun_dispatch.view import index, tautaun_request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tautaun_dispatch' is there a different format as well for the from?

Comment: check the `view` spelling it might be `views`, need to see your project structure.

Comment: https://screenrec.com/share/Ra5mNJ9QqU thats my view

Comment: `tauntaun_dispatch # ls tauntaun_dispatch` output ?

Answer (score 1):

version 1... use

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

SO :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('request/', tauntaun_request),
    url('', tauntaun_request),
]
```

> > > > version 2. .. and 3. ...  use

```
from django.urls import path
```

So :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('request/', tauntaun_request),
    path('', tauntaun_request),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

No module named 'tautaun_dispatch' is there a different format as well for the from? For this you have to:

Add tautaun_dispatch in your installed apps section in settings.py file of your project.

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tauntaun_dispatch', 
]   -------Thats what I had and still wouldn't work

Comment: Try to import the package name. you can mention views.tauntaun_dispatch if you have your views.py in contians the tauntaun_dispatch view name . 
Try 
from tantaun_dispatch import views
path('', views.tauntaun_request),